# How should I validate the presence of fields that create an instance that doesn't have a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A sign in form simply populates the sessions hash, and so doesn't have a model. As such, I don't know where to put validations for the sign in form. How should I validate presence of the username and password? Should I just do it with javascript on the clientside? I suppost that makes sense, how could I iterate through the errors hash if it were to fail validations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple, you can realize it using `ActiveModel`. Just create a class as below and add some validations

```
class Session
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :username, :password
  validates_presence_of :username, :password

  def initialize(attrs = {})
    attrs.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end

s = Session.new(username: 'Abc')
=> #<Session:0x000000058a3270 @username="Abc">
s.valid?
s.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000058ad900 ... @messages={:password=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

And your form should automatically show error messages if exists.

Comment: What is the `persisted?` method for?

Comment: Indicates if the model is persisted. You can remove it if you want, by default it will return false.

Comment: Sorry, I think I accidentally down voted! SO won't let me vote it up again unless you edit the answer...